# How to scroll ViewPager with the scroll of only Horizontal RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

[image]

I am making a view similar like in MMT app home page shown in the image attached in which the View Pager is scrolls only by scrolling of Recycler View down to View Pager.

I tried some code and achieved it somewhat but I am facing some problem.

1. The view pager is scrolling with Recycler view when I am scrolling it but ViewPager scrolls more and next image getting clipped.
2. View Pager is also scrolling separately if I am scrolling it manually but I want it to scroll only when Recycler View scroll.

Here is the screenshot of what I did and what problem I am facing.

In the screenshot, you can see that I am getting the half-visible next image in View Pager on the scroll of Recycler View.

[image]

Here is my code where I am scrolling the view pager with Recycler View scroll

```
enter code here


      recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
         @Override
         public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
           }
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            viewPager.scrollBy(dx, dy);
         }
```

Here is my code where i am setting adapter to View Pager and Recycler View

```
enter code here

    StoryViewPagerAdapter storyViewPagerAdapter = new 
    StoryViewPagerAdapter(this, viewPagerImagesList);
    viewPager.setAdapter(storyViewPagerAdapter);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(storiesAdapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(viewPagerImagesList.size());
```

Can anyone suggest tell me what I am forgetting to consider here?

Thanks in Advance.